# security rules for grouped collection and inner collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to set firebase security rules for all collections in one collection with Firebase Firestore.
I have a collection named `game_lookup` inside of it I have many named ducuments, One is contest and the others are there. and all of them have many inner level sub collections.

Like

> /game_lookup/arcade/level_-6NVwtc0cp-/1

I want to set rules for contest a different and rest of others same rules.

For contest I have defined

```
 match /game_lookup/{document} {
    allow read: if isAuthenticated();

  match /tournament/{document} {
    allow read: if isAuthenticated();
  }

  match /tournament_players_list/{document} {
    allow read, write: if isAuthenticated();
   
    match /allusersPostion/{document} {
      allow read, write : if false;
    }
    
    match /percentile/{document} {
      allow read, write : if false;
    }
  }

  match /tournament_template/{document} {
    allow read, write : if false;
  }
}
```

Now this
`/game_lookup/arcade/master/`,

`/game_lookup/arcade/level_-6NVwtc0cp-/1`

I am not able to access it.

[image]

**EDIT**

How I allow only to those users who are authorized to `/game_lookup/contest/tournament_players_list/0Bqbujy16qOYa8YAIbQT/joined/{userId}`

I have tried

```
   match /joined/{document} {
        allow read, create, update: if isAuthenticated() && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
```

Not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access `/game_lookup/arcade/master/`, because you have not defined any rules for `master` subcollection. So define rules like this:

```
match /game_lookup/{document} {
  allow read: if isAuthenticated();
  
  match /master/{document} {
    allow read: if isAuthenticated();
  }
  // ... other rules

  // For "/game_lookup/arcade/level_-6NVwtc0cp-/1', you also define as below
  match /level_-6NVwtc0cp-/{document} {
    // define rules.
    // rules here will define access for '/game_lookup/arcade/level_-6NVwtc0cp-/1'
  }
}

// **EDIT**
// below works on playground but have not been tested on physical device.
// you can add a more specific rule like this to determine permissions on
// game_lookup/master documents.
match /game_lookup/master {
  allow read: if isAuthenticated();
  // this should determine access for master documents
}
// with this, you can define seperate rules for collection/documents 
that only exist in master documents (per our chat in the comments)
```

Comment: acutally, this master collection exist for arcade but may not exist for duel for this even this needs to be define seperately ?

Comment: Yes, you need to define all seperately.

Comment: You can check my updated answer... `match /game_lookup/master{// this should determine access for master documents}` works on playground but not yet tested on physical device

Comment: I thought there could be an answer that stop me from writing the same multiple times.

Comment: @cakePHP Can you please let us know if this answers your question?